# Exclude Products from existing Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

we have around 1300 shopping cart price rules. we now added a new product that we want't to exclude from all of our shopping cart price rules. what is the best way to do that? I though of updating the conditions of the shopping cart price rules programmatically, but I have no idea how to handle the serialized conditions.

Michael

Comment: You want to "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions"? There is only available for product: "Attribute set" or "Category". How do you select your product? By category or specific attribute set?

Comment: hi, yes this product is in a category that can be used to exclude it from shopping cart price rules. i know how to do it in the admin backend, but as we have so many rules i need a programmatically solution to update all of them with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is some more OO solution, but my code just works.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
        ->getCollection()
        ->load();


foreach ($model as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item->getId(), [11,12,13])) continue; //which rules you want to modify, or comment this line to modify all

    $actions = unserialize($item->getActionsSerialized());

    $actions['conditions'][] = [
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
        'attribute' => 'category_ids',
        'operator' => '==',
        'value' => 3, // insert here your category id
        'is_value_processed' => false
    ];

    $item->setActionsSerialized(serialize($actions));
    $item->save();
}
```